# Can't Override UIView.Draw Method

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin, draw

I need to override the draw method, but I get the error message:

> Draw(System.Drawing.PointF)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115).

This is what I do: I create a new project, add an empty class and try to override.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using CoreGraphics;
using CoreImage;
using Foundation;
using CoreAnimation;

namespace Test
{
    public class Tester : UIView
    {
        CGPath path;

        public override void Draw (PointF rect){
            base.Draw ();
        }


        public Tester ()
        {
            path = new CGPath ();
        }

    }
}
```

Actually I'm trying the Xamarin's tutorial.
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/graphics_animation_walkthrough/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you create a program with the Unified API (see "using CoreImage" at the top).   In Unified API, we no longer use PointF, SizeF or RectangleF, as those are 32-bit structures, so they do not work on 32/64 bit modes.

In Unified, you need to use "CGRect" instead of "RectangleF"

So to fix your program, all you have to do is replace "RectangleF" with "CGRect"

The tutorials currently reflect the Classic API, and once we officially release the final version of Unified, they will be switched over.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override different methods. The original method has no arguments. If you want to override the Draw method, you need to delete your Draw function arguments.

Comment: No, because they use the same method. If you see, inside their Draw method, they do base.Draw(rect). Maybe you need to do the same.

Comment: Yes, I change the PointF to CGRect and it works. But now, I have another problem:
The Tester class is was an empty class, I've created.
My principal class, the view controller class is another. This seems nobie, but how I use the Tester class, created using the Xamarin's exemple, on my principal class? I want to do a line on screen...